# Why using repmat() for expanding array?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab

I want to load a csv file to Matlab using `testread()`, since the data in it has more than 2 million records, so I should preallocate the array for those data.

Suppose I cannot know the exact length of arrays, the docs of MATLAB v6.5 recommend me to use `repmat()` for my expanding array. The original words in the doc is below:

> "In cases where you cannot preallocate, see if you can increase the
>   size of your array using the repmat function. repmat tries to get you
>   a contiguous block of memory for your expanding array".

I really don't know how to use the repmat for expanding?

Does it mean by estimating a rough number of the length for `repmat()` to preallocating, and then remove the empty elements?

If so, how is that different from preallocating using `zeros()` or `cell()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation also says:

> When you preallocate a block of memory to hold a matrix of some type
>   other than double, it is more memory efficient and sometimes faster to
>   use the repmat function for this.
>
> The statement below uses zeros to preallocate a 100-by-100 matrix of
>   uint8. It does this by first creating a full matrix of doubles, and
>   then converting the matrix to uint8. This costs time and uses memory
>   unnecessarily.
>
> ```
> A = int8(zeros(100));
> ```
>
> Using repmat, you create only one double, thus reducing your memory
>   needs.
>
> ```
> A = repmat(int8(0), 100, 100);
> ```

Therefore, the advantage is if you want a datatype other than doubles, you can use repmat to replicate a non-double datatype.

Also see: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance, which suggests:

```
data1(1000,3000) = 0
```

instead of:

```
data1 = zeros(1000,3000)
```

to avoid initialisation of other elements.

As for dynamic resizing, `repmat` can be used to concisely double the size of your array (a common method which results in amortized O(1) appends for each element):

```
data = [0];
i = 1;
while another element
    ...
    if i > numel(data)
      data = repmat(data,1,2); % doubles the size of data
    end
    data(i) = element
    i = i + 1;
end
```

And yes, after you have gathered all your elements, you can resize the array to remove empty elements at the end.